# How to take a pic and view in Android?

Tags: android

I'm learning Android and I would like to take a photo and view. I found so many incomplete HOWTOs. Would some one explain step by step how can I take a photo and view with Android?

Comment: Do you want to use the camera UI already provided (as Abhinav suggested) or create your own UI to snap a picture?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to take a photo in Android (and the best possibly) is to fire an Intent for the camera app which will handle the photo taking and previewing part for you. A detailed how-to is [here](http://achorniy.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/howto-launch-android-camera-using-intents/).

After you get a File reference for the stored image, you can display the image in an ImageView. Keep in mind that this will not support pinch, pan or zoom. You will have to implement them yourself.

Comment: How to get the file reference